# Ajax jquery success scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I have this ajax call to a `doop.php`.

```
    function doop(){
        var old = $(this).siblings('.old').html();
        var new = $(this).siblings('.new').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'doop.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'before=' + old + '&after=' + new,
            success: function(resp) {
                if(resp == 1) {
                    $(this).siblings('.old').html(new);
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

My problem is that the `$(this).siblings('.old').html(new);` line isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

thanks.. 
all helpful comments/answers are voted up.

**Update:** it appears that half of the problem was the scope (thanks for the answers that helped me clarify that), but the other half is that I'm trying to use ajax in a synchronous manner. I've created a new post

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa whoa whoa. `new` is a reserved word: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Don't worry about new, it's called something else in my code. Just called it new to make the code more understandable for you guys

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all `new` is [a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words). You need to rename that variable.

To answer your question, Yes, you need to save `this` in a variable outside the success callback, and reference it inside your success handler code:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(resp) {
        if(resp == 1) {
            $(that).siblings('.old').html($new);
        }
    }
})
```

This is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

Comment: Hmm, weird, I tried something very similar to what you've done, but I did `var saveit = $(this);` didn't work. I'll try this one now.. Also don't worry about new, it's called something else in my code.

Comment: @Chris: re: `new`, I figured as much. :)

Comment: @Chris: re the closure not working, make sure `doop` is itself referring to the expected `this`. If you just call `doop()` for example, `this` will just point to the `window` object.

Comment: Ok, after the closure, I'm able to target the right this/that (I tested it with show/hide and i know it's targeting the right thing). However, it's not updating the html.. I'm doing some troubleshooting and will update my answer above, please check back when you get a chance, thanks.

Comment: Now that I've done my troubleshooting, I've come to the conclusion that the second half of the problem is that I should be using synchronous ajax. not asynchronous. Updaing my question above and posting a new question.

Comment: You're correct on the `new` keyword, but this adds far too much code bloat in a long list where it's added dynamically, each var would have to be unique, where as in the answer below, using `context: this` does it once and has much more flexible use cases.

Answer (score 52):

You should use the **context** setting as in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function doop(){
    var old = $(this).siblings('.old').html();
    var newValue = $(this).siblings('.new').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'doop.php',
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        data: 'before=' + old + '&after=' + newValue,
        success: function(resp) {
            if(resp == 1) {
                $(this).siblings('.old').html(newValue);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

"this" will be transfer to the success scope and will act as expected.

Comment: You really should not use reserved words like `new` as variable names.

Comment: Agreeing with Nick - this is the correct approach.  Consider that the "save it in another variable" approach won't work if you have function "doop" called when one of multiple buttons are clicked or some other such duplication.

Comment: +1 Much more flexible answer than the selected one, in our case, the var would have to be unique for every single item in a very long list of items adding code bloat, this is a few short characters and gives much more flexible use cases.

Answer (score 7):

`this` is bound to the object to which the executing function was applied. That could be some AJAX response object, or the global object (`window`), or something else (depending on the implementation of `$.ajax`.

> Do I need to capture $(this) into a variable before entering the $.ajax call, and then pass it as a parameter to the $.ajax call? or do I need to pass it to the anonymous success function? If that's going to solve the problem, where do I pass it to the $.ajax?

You do indeed need a way to capture the value of `this` before defining the `success` function. Creating a closure is the way to do this. You need to define a separate variable (e.g. `self`):

```
function doop() {
    var old = $(this).siblings('.old').html();
    var new = $(this).siblings('.new').val();

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'doop.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'before=' + old + '&after=' + new,
        success: function(resp) {
            if(resp == 1) {
                $(self).siblings('.old').html(new);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

The `success` function will retain the value of `self` when invoked, and should behave as you expected.

Comment: Thanks +1. This is the same as crescentfresh's answer and it solves "part of the problem".. will update the question with more troubleshooting.