# jQuery AJAX - Success function scope - passing in 'this'

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope

Struggling to get my head around AJAX success scope.

I am trying to load some data from an AJAX call, then attach it using jQuery to an already existing `ul`

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope) helped me out , but I can't work out how to reference specific elements from 'this'.

So I've passed `this` into the success function as `that` , but this line:

```
$('li.loading').before(nextLoad);
```

Fails with:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Im assuming , I need to use `that` followed my my element, but cannot work out the syntax.

```
                  var that = this;

                  $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: url,
                        async: true,
                        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',                      
                        success: function(data) 
                        {                                   

                             $.each(data.products, function(key, val) 
                             {                                
                                items.push('<li class="product"><a href="product.html"><span class="store-badge"></span><img src="'+val.image+'" width="124" height="166" /><h3>'+val.title+'</h3></a></li>');                                  
                             });

                             var nextLoad = items;  

                             if (loadNumber <= 4) {
                                 $('li.loading').before(nextLoad);
                             };
                             if (loadNumber >= 4) {
                                 $('li.loading').hide();
                             };

                             $('.scroll-horizontal').mCustomScrollbar("update");                            

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            console.log('failed');
                        }
                        });
```

EDIT:

Console logging that results in :

```
Window
Infinity: Infinity
$: function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
Array: function Array() { [native code] }
ArrayBuffer: function ArrayBuffer() { [native code] }
Attr: function Attr() { [native code] }
Audio: [object Function]
AudioProcessingEvent: function AudioProcessingEvent() { [native code] }
BeforeLoadEvent: function BeforeLoadEvent() { [native code] }
Blob: function Blob() { [native code] }
Boolean: function Boolean() { [native code] }
//CONTIUNES
```

Console logging nextload also results in

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(nextLoad); console.log($('li.loading'))` and update your question with results?

Comment: The variable `items` is not defined in your code above, but I assume it's an array since you're `push`ing to it? If so, `nextLoad` is also an array, and you can't use `before()` to insert an array, only jQuery objects or strings with HTML will work with DOM insertion methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing data to `items` :

```
items.push('<li class="product"><a href= ......
```

which would indicate that `items` is in fact an array ?

Then you do:

```
var nextLoad = items;
```

turning `nextLoad` effectively into an array as well.

Now when you're trying to do :

```
$('li.loading').before(nextLoad);
```

you're trying to insert an array before the `li` elements that have the `.loading` class, and since the DOM does'nt really support inserting arrays into it, you get an error.

Comment: right. Makes sense. Fixed this by looping over 'items' and then using before for each string rather than trying to put the array in . Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = $(this);
```

try this jquery