# Promises and Scope

Tags: jquery

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){

        var prm_delete = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/gateway/delete',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id')}
        });

        prm_delete.done(function(data){

            //how do I get the button? 
            //$(this) does not work
        });

    });
```

Above is my delete button code, I use a promise to send the id of the button. When the promise is done I need to get the button that was pressed so I can highlight it.

I'm having trouble with scope as done runs a function, how can I pass in the button that was pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax jquery success scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option context of ajax:

```
 var prm_delete = $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/gateway/delete',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id')}
        });
```

You could bind context too:

```
prm_delete.done(function(data){

            //how do I get the button? 
            //$(this) does not work
        }.bind(this));
```

Which is the same as usin jQuery `$.proxy` (bringing support for older browsers):

```
prm_delete.done($.proxy(function(data){

                //how do I get the button? 
                //$(this) does not work
            },this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to store `$(this)` in another variable in order to access later:

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var prm_delete = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/gateway/delete',
        data: {id: $(this).attr('id')}
    });

    prm_delete.done(function(data){
        // Now you can use that to access the `.btn-delete`
    });

});
```