# Add a link to an online user's div, and remove for online

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Right now, every time a user logs in, all the posts made by that user will turn green, while all the offline users' posts are grey.

I want to add a link to a javascript function for when the div is green, and a different link for when it's grey. I did this in php no problem but I want it to work realtime just like the color change without a page refresh.

**The html**

```
<div class="main_ads status" id="user'.$user_id.'">post</div>
```

**status.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array = array();

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` = 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){  
        $array[] = 'user'.$row['user_id'];  // this adds each online user id to the array         
    }
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

**ajax code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                               
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'status.php',
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.length > 0){                               // if at least 1 is online
                        $('.status').each(function(){                   // loop through each of the user posts                      
                            var userid = $(this).attr('id'); // get the user#
                            if($.inArray(userid, data) !== -1){  // if userid # in the returned data array set to online
                               $(this).css({background: '#40A547'}); 
                            } else{                                     // if not, set to offline
                                $(this).css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
                            }
                        });
                    } else {                                            // if no one is online, set all to offline
                        $('.status').css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
                    }           
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
```

I tried to think of a way to do this and thought to assign a variable with a html  tag that will be different for online and offline but wasn't sure how to call that variable from the ajax code into html.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: See here for a solution to a problem you're not seing :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope [i.e. ajax scope]

Comment: What would happen with `setInterval()` if the AJAX request takes longer than 2 seconds?... Just something to think about.

Comment: it's just for testing. i will make it 15sec. @UnamataSanatarai I get the logic there but I am not really getting it to work that way. I made a var that equals to the link i want and put in as .siblings('.status').html(new); ('new' being the link)

Comment: could you show me an example in an answer of how to do this?

Comment: How about definining two functions each containing a link for online and offline user, and add a `onclick` event to the div calling the function based on the user status? Or add an `<a>` tag inside the div (so that it covers the inside text) and change the `href` attribute accordingly.

Comment: My problem is how to change the href attribute as you said. How do I take it from the ajax into the the div? and I want one regular link like www.example.com (for offline) and one to a javascript function (for online)

Comment: divs do not have `href`s. You'd need to make it an `a` and I suggest hardcoding the link for offline only to override it with javascript when online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the **[wrapInner()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)** property of jQuery. This could enclose the text place inside your div into `<a></a>` tags such as:

```
if($.inArray(userid, data) !== -1){  // if userid # in the returned data array set to online
  $(this).css({background: '#40A547'}); 
  //for the online users, you could fill in the javascript function
  $(this).wrapInner('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:online_clicked();"></a>');
} else{                                     // if not, set to offline
  $(this).css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
   //over here write the link for offline users
   $(this).wrapInner("<a href='www.google.com'></a>");
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3R8rN/2/)**

Comment: that's more of what i want. Is there a way to wrap the div rather than just the text inside the div? I want the padding of the text to be link-able as well

Comment: @Gadgetster For that simply use `.wrap()` in place of `.wrapInner()`

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not add inline styles, use css classes.
2. In case the request takes longer than 2 seconds, abort it!
3. I suggest not using `id`'s, mabye `data-user` or `.user#` as class

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_ads status" id="user1">post1</div>
...
<div class="main_ads status" id="user10">post10</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.online{
    background:red;
    padding:3px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var global_ajax_request = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        if (global_ajax_request){
            global_ajax_request.abort();
        }
        global_ajax_request = $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.status').removeClass('online');
                for(var i in data){
                    $('#'+data[i]).addClass('online');
                }
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
$('.status').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('online')){
        alert('function for ONLINE');
    }else{
        alert('function for OFFLINE');
    }
});
```

**Explanations:**

`global_ajax_request` holds the reference to a request. Just before launching a new one, kill the old one. **(!)** This will make the browser not listen for a response, but the server will continue to work.

Each time you get a response, clear the `online` class and add it only to the returned `userId`'s. (This should be Optimized.)

The last bit `$('.status').on(...)` will be fired each time someone clicks on a div. Then inside you see if it's green (online) or not and launch the appropriate function.

Comment: I am confused about your first point. And it's 2 seconds for testing only. It will be 15 seconds later. And can you explain what your code does? I can't see how to add a link. would 'online' class contain the link in it and it is add to the div?

Comment: #1 try to avoid `.css('background...)`. #2 even if it's 15 seconds, it's, in my opinion, good practice to abort any previous requests, as they may still be pending. #3 sorry, missed the part about the links. I updated it. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I did something similar to that and it worked as well! thank you for the help!