# Jquery AJAX calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my app, a  displays available timeslots (for appointment). I want to add a class 'taken' to the slots () which are already taken. For this I wrote the following code.

```
$("td").each(function(){

    var send = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/check-availability.php',
        context: this,
        data:{"slot":send},
        dataType:'json',
        type:'get',
        success: function(result){

            console.log(result);

            if (result.status === "taken") {
                $(this).addClass('taken');

            };

        }
    });

});
```

It's supposed to perform an ajax call, and if the result for a slot is 'taken', add the class 'taken' to corresponding . It does the ajax call part, but adds the class to all td elements in the table, not just the taken ones.

the check-availability.php, returns 'taken' when called it in browser but nothing happens. Also, when the condition is changed into **result.status === "notTaken"**, all the s are added the class 'taken'

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you add a alert/logging stmt in the if class to see whether it is working

Comment: this not get after ajax call save this then use that variable after ajax ....

Comment: try `context: $(this)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I did. I'm getting notTaken as response for all slots. But when called the check-availability.php file on browser, it gives 'taken' for the one slot which is already in database, and notTaken for the ones which are not.

Comment: then the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: provide the content of `check-availability.php` please

Comment: I think the problem is there are too many white spaces around the 'slot'. ( var send = $(this).text(); ) . Removed them and problem solved. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").each(function(){
var that = this;
var send = $(this).text();

$.ajax({
    url:'ajax/check-availability.php',
    context: this,
    data:{"slot":send},
    dataType:'json',
    type:'get',
    success: function(result){

        console.log(result);

        if (result.status === "taken") {
            $(that).addClass('taken');

        };

        }
    });

});
```

see this for more reference:
[$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

[Ajax jquery success scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope)

Comment: since the `context: this` is set the problem should be something else

Answer (score -1):

instead of success, try using `.done()`

example

```
`
 $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/check-availability.php',
        context: this,
        data:{"slot":send},
        dataType:'json',
        type:'get'
    }).done(function(result) {
console.log(result);
            if (result.status === "taken") {
                $(this).addClass('taken');

            };
        });
`
```

Comment: This didn't change anything.