# Jquery Ajax deleting records from db in HMVC codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

View file

```
<button class="btn btn-danger deleteBlog" onclick="deleteBlog(<?php echo $row->id;?>)"></button>
```

Ajax part

```
function deleteBlog(id) {
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url()?>";
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'blog/delete',
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: id},
            success: function () {
                alert('ajax success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ajax failure');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert(id + " not deleted");
    }
}
```

controller file

```
function delete(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->_delete($id);
}

function _delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('mdl_blog');
    $this->mdl_blog->_delete($id);
}
```

model

```
function _delete($id)
{
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($data);
}
```

Hello Guyz I am bit confused with this ajax deleting concept I might be doing some silly mistake or I am totally out of the concept of ajax. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: Any errors in console??

Comment: Have you tried putting response to your success callback? See this.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope

Comment: In model, I can't see `$table` variable is used and also `$data` variable is not initialized. Also, you don't return true or false to controller and third, you don't echo back some value to AJAX.

Comment: I am using HMVC codeigniter.

Comment: Their is no error in console, I am getting success alert but the delete is not happening in db

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this code:

```
$table = $this->get_table();
```

You don't need this line in CI model delete function..

And in controller:

```
function delete(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->_delete($id);
    echo "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the query with `$this->db->last_query();` to check if current query to delete it's ok.

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html